# How to Count total Medal of Sports

Tags: sql

I am working on School Sport Project..In this i have a table:-
result(State,Point)

For medal i have following criteria:-

```
Gold  - 7 Point
Silver- 5 Points
Bronze- 4 Points
```

I want to count total number Gold,Silver and bronze medal obtained by each State..For this i used following query:

```
select STATE,sum(Point) as MEDAL from [Sheet2$] Group by STATE order by sum(Point) desc
```

but it counts total number of points only.I want total number of Gold,Silver and Bronze medals also..So please help me

Comment: In which column the value Gold, Silver and Bronze are stored? Please specify your database engine like SQL server, Oracle etc.

Comment: Could you please give us your table structure ?

Comment: You should provide the database/table structure as well

Comment: Are you storing ONLY points? So that for example to find out the number of Gold medals you'd have to select count(*) where point=7?

Comment: Try grouping by State,medal_type and using count instead of sum

Comment: I am storing points only.Each State gets some points from 7 to 1 for each sport type. On the basis of points I have to calculate Medals

Comment: feed your insert query if possible for more understanding

Comment: its quite difficult as your total points may 35 or 40 in that case how can you count whether its 7 sliver or 5 gold for 35 points OR 8 sliver or 10 bronze for 40 points, So you need to redesign your approach for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing some conditional logic - I'm assuming here that you have no other columns, and the data isn't already aggregated in any way, but, maybe something like:

```
SELECT      STATE,
            SUM(Point) AS MEDAL,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GoldCount,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SilverCount,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BronzeCount

FROM        [Sheet2$]

GROUP BY    STATE 

ORDER BY    SUM(Point) DESC
```

Comment: I think its a THEN 1 instead of WHEN 1

Comment: Sir One more thing if i use your this query in window application to select the data stored excel then it shows error:---ERROR [42000ׁ] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'....Can you please help me here

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you would determine the medals from the points in the table, then you can group that result to count the medals:

```
select
  STATE, Medal, count(*) as [Count]
from
  (select
    STATE,
    case
      when Point >= 7 then 'Gold'
      when Point >= 5 then 'Silver'
      when Point >= 4 then 'Bronze'
      else null
    end as Medal
  from
    [Sheet2$]
  ) x
group by
  STATE, Medal
order by
  STATE
```

Comment: It now appropriatly for me

Comment: This shows the state names according to count of medals such as exam:-  Delhi Medal:1 Count:-1,Delhi Meda:1 Count:1

Comment: i want it as:----state and then their Total Gold,Total bronze and Total silver

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the other strategies. Assuming your table looks like this:

```
+-------+--------+
| state | points |
+-------+--------+
| IL    |      7 |
| ON    |      3 |
| ON    |      7 |
...
| TX    |      7 |
+-------+--------+
```

Then something like this would get the medal counts:

```
SELECT
  state,
  count(*) AS medal
FROM your_table
GROUP BY state, points
ORDER BY state, points desc
```

Comment: Note: "above" doesn't work here, as answers with the same points are ordered randomly.

Comment: It now appropriatly for me