# Reorganize data structure in sqlite (with COUNT?)

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Currently I have the following data structure, listing sport results:

```
table_org:
--------------------------------
Name  Club Place Irrelevant_data
--------------------------------
John  ABC    1        xyz
John  ABC    2        abc
John  ABC    1        def
Jane  DEF    1        abc
Jane  DEF    3        ref
Mark  ABC    2        stu
```

This is currently imported to `SQLite Manager` from a `csv` file generated by a `python 2.7.3` web scraping script. The number of rows is 1000.

I would like to get the following data structure in a new table:

```
table_new:
-----------------------------
Name  Club Gold Silver Bronze
-----------------------------
John  ABC    2    1      0
Jane  DEF    1    0      1
Mark  ABC    0    1      0
```

What is this operation called and how can I achieve it?

My tool would be `SQLite Manager` itself or `python` modules.

During my research I found that perhaps the `COUNT` method should be used somehow, but I could not find relevant examples. Please note that I am a newbie in databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [generate a medal count table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911512/190597) like this:

```
SELECT Name, Club, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Place = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Gold,
SUM(CASE WHEN Place = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Silver,
SUM(CASE WHEN Place = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Bronze
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Name, Club
```

which yields

```
+------+------+------+--------+--------+
| Name | Club | Gold | Silver | Bronze |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+
| Jane | DEF  |  1   |   0    |   1    |
| John | ABC  |  2   |   1    |   0    |
| Mark | ABC  |  0   |   1    |   0    |
+------+------+------+--------+--------+
```